# How to fix Delphi XE3 migration errors?

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, delphi-xe3

I am migrating my Delphi 5 application to Delphi XE3. I am getting some erros while compiling it. Can someone please help me to resolve these. Thanks for help in advance.

1. I am not able to find defination of function `OemToChar` in XE3. When I Ctrl+Click on that function it shows message `Unable to locate 'WinAPI.Windows.pas'`. I am not able to open any delphi component file. What is the location of windows.pas located on the system ? or How to resolve it ?
2. `Incompatiable Types: 'PAnsiChar' and 'PWideChar'` in below function on line with `OemToChar(p1, p2)`.

```
function OemToAnsi(const Str: string): string;
var
  p1,
  p2: PChar;
begin
  p1 := PChar(Str);
  p2 := StrNew(p1);
  OemToChar(p1, p2);
  Result := StrPas(p2);
  StrDispose(p2);
end;
```

1. Getting error `'Low Bound Exceeds High Bound'` in following code.

```
function StrToRichText(const Str: string): string;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for i := 1 to Length(Str) do
  begin
    case Str[i] of
      #128 .. #255 :
        Result := Result + '\''' + LowerCase(IntToHex(Ord(Str[i]), 2));
      '\','{','}':
        Result := Result + '\' + Str[i];
    else
      Result := Result + Str[i];
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `OemToAnsi` function should look like this:

```
function OemToAnsi(const Str: AnsiString): AnsiString;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Str));
  OemToCharA(PAnsiChar(Str), PAnsiChar(Result));
end;
```

But perhaps you'd be better with

```
function OemToWide(const Str: AnsiString): string;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Str));
  OemToChar(PAnsiChar(Str), PChar(Result));
end;
```

As for your `StrToRichText`, that looks more difficult. It clearly only accepts ANSI input. If you want to stick with ANSI then just change the declaration to

```
function StrToRichText(const Str: AnsiString): AnsiString;
```

RTF is encoded with 7 bit ASCII. To make that function work with Unicode input you'd need to escape any characters with ordinal >= 128. The escaping is described, for example, on the Wikipedia [Rich Text Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format#Character_encoding) page. I'll leave that as an exercise for you!

---

Before you go much further you need to read Marco Cantù's white paper: [Delphi and Unicode](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38980).

Comment: thanks david. All above errors resolved. I will go through that paper surely.

Answer (score 4):

1. 'OemToChar()' is declared in 'Winapi.Windows.pas', just like the IDE says.  Make sure your `uses` clause includes `Winapi.Windows`, or that `Winapi` is inluded in your Project's "Unit Scope Names" field in the Project Options if the `uses` clause includes 'Windows' instead (which it likely does since you are migrating).
2. In D2009+, `OemToChar()` maps to `OemToCharW()` now, not to `OemToCharA()` anymore.  The first parameter of both functions is a `PAnsiChar`.  In D2009+, `PChar` maps to `PWideChar` now, not to `PAnsiChar` anymore, so you need to re-write your code accordingly, eg:

   ```
   function OemToAnsi(const Str: AnsiString): string;
   var
     S: String;
   begin
     SetLength(S, Length(Str));
     OemToChar(PAnsiChar(Str), PChar(S));
     Result := PChar(S);
   end;
   ```

   However, you should re-think why you still need to deal with OEM strings in the first place.  They don't make as much sense in a Unicode world, and they are rarely even used in an Ansi world.
3. Another case where you need to re-write the code to account for `Char=WideChar` now, since character ranges are much larger than Ansi character ranges.  You I would use ordinals instead (you should also take UTF-16 surrogates into account properly, but I will leave that as an exercise for you), eg:

   ```
   function StrToRichText(const Str: string): string;
   var
     i: integer;
   begin
     Result := '';
     for i := 1 to Length(Str) do
     begin            
       case Ord(Str[i]) of
         128..255:
           Result := Result + '\''' + LowerCase(IntToHex(Ord(Str[i]), 2));
         Ord('\'), Ord('{'), Ord('}'):
           Result := Result + '\' + Str[i];
       else
         Result := Result + Str[i];
       end;
     end;
   end;
   ```

Comment: Is the Result := PChar(S) needed? Can the output be a shorter string than the input?

Comment: Winapi is inluded in your Project's "Unit Scope Names" field in the Project Options already still I am not able to open any files. :( Any perticuler environment settings are needed for that?

Comment: Sounds like the IDE's Library paths are not configured correctly.

Comment: can anyone help me to set these path? Which path I should mention?

Comment: I know this is old, but I recently converted a project from D2009 to XE3 and although the Unit Scope Names looked correct in Project Options it would not compile. I had to open the project file in a text editor and move the DCC_UnitSearchPath directive into the correct PropertyGroup manually and then it worked... just in case someone else has this problem.

Answer (score 1):

About Unicode you're already been addressed. There is also a lot of articles in google.

---

I also suggest you to read about class helpers and record helpers - that might help you with re-introducing some obsoleted functions in libraries, and delaying re-working of the codebase.

That also might help you to override errors like

```
var r: TRect;
 ....
  with r do begin
 ....
     B := IntersetRect( A1, A2 );
 ....
  end;
```

---

Regarding `OemToChar` - i guest t you'd better use convenient wrappers, that were given in `RxLib` in Delphi 5 times, then you'd migrate to `Jedi Code Library` and your code would just not have that problem.

However now you're at XEn - you can  perfectly live without that.
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SetCodePage

```
 var sa, so: RawByteString;
 ....
     sa := source; SetCodePage(sa, GetACP(), true);
     so := sa;     SetCodePage(so, GetOEMCP(), true);
```

Similar code works in my project, where i parse legacy binary data.

If you only care about one single locale, then you probably can hardcode this.

```
 var sa: AnsiString[1251]; so: AnsiString[866]; su: UnicodeString;
 ....
     sa := source; 
 ....
     su := sa; // Win32: MultiByteToWideCharBuf - official Microsoft way
     so := su; // Win32: WideCharToMultiByteBuf - official Microsoft way
 ....
     so := sa;  // double conversion in one step
     // did not tested, but should work accorrding to doc.   
     // looks like obsolete Win16 OemToChar
     // and like codepage-to-codepage direct transcoding
     //     routines from JCL.SF.NET
```